# using same docker container for spring boot and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker

Jsut getting started with docker and cloud platforms, so my question might seem a bit vague. But since system design largely depends on who's designing the application I am a bit confused.

My project is quite simple:

1. Authentication
2. CRUD operations on posts and collection of posts

So a total of 10/12 apis. And I selected mongodb for my application. I was thinking about using one instance of aws, install docker and run both mongodb and spring boot application from that single instance.

I asked around a bit but got confusing answers like I need to use dynamodb and cannot run both mongo and my application from one instance.

I am not worried about security as this is more of a fun project than an actual large scale one.

My questions are:

1. Is it a good idea to do so? Example: if I need to fire up another instance that instance wont have access to data from the instance if I am correct.

N.B: I know that using db in containers is not a good practice according to some people. Only reason I thought of this solution because this way I only need to pay for the instance.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is simply for learning, or for very small scale usage where you're not very worried about performance or reliability, the architecture you propose is perfectly reasonable. There is always more than one way to do it. If you're hearing from others that you should use Dynamodb, or that you should have separate instances, or that it isn't robust enough, etc, IMO that's coming from a narrow minded perspective.

You can use [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to define your two containers and easily connect them. Or you could simply use Docker and start/stop them manually. It's perfectly fine to use a single instance for this. However, if it's just a sandbox for learning purposes, do you really gain anything beyond just running on your local system?

Important caveat: this architecture would not be suitable for a real world use case that serves a purpose beyond learning.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what would be an ideal architecture in your opinion if this were a real world application?

Comment: That’s a more complex question that I won’t be getting in to in a comment. :)

Comment: I understand that. I guess one can write an article about that. But I wanted to know since will be better if I run db on one instance and the application on other since I can easily connect the multiple instances for db using docker compose?

Comment: In a nutshell, for a production set up, at a minimum you’d want 2 instances on the front end with a load balancer, plus 2 database instances (primary + standby) for redundancy.